# The summation formula for sin.

Tags: complex-numbers

Please tell me I'm wrong.  Someone I know called last night to tell me that the familar function $\sin(x+y) = \sin x \cos y +\cos x \sin y$ is valid only when $x$ and $y$ are real.  I argued with him, saying that analytic functions that agree on the reals have to agree everywhere.  He said something about that's only for one variable.  So I said, well fix an a and ask about
$\sin (x+a)-\sin x\cos a-\sin a\cos x$ now an analytic function of one variable that vanishes for all real $x$, hence for all complex $x$.  Am I doing something wrong?  I really fear for my friend, a fine mathematician who is going through a very rough patch in his personal life.

Comment: The addition formula also holds for complex $x,y$. Follows from the identity theorem and the real case. Fix $y\in \mathbb{R}$ to get it for all $x\in \mathbb{C},\, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then fix $x\in \mathbb{C}$ to get it also for $y\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Or you can prove it by calculation with power series. That's more work, but also fun.

Comment: Wish your buddy would call me and chat about trig. I would love that!

Comment: What is the position is of the Catholic church on the summation formula for sin ?

Answer (score 3):

For all complex,

$$\sin(x+y)=\frac{e^{ix+iy}-e^{-ix-iy}}{2i}$$
while
$$\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y=\frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})(e^{iy}+e^{-iy})+(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})(e^{iy}-e^{-iy})}{4i}=\frac{2e^{ix}e^{iy}-2e^{-ix}e^{-iy}}{4i}.$$

Comment: Finally, I got him to admit he'd erred.

Comment: Good for you ! Did he also confess other crimes and misdemeanours?